# Quoting error when executing a Drill query from JetBrains JDBC driver

Tags: jdbc, jetbrains-ide, apache-drill, intellij-datagrip

I have a custom datasource driver in JetBrans (Rider 2019.2) which uses apache-drill-1.17.jar JDBC driver (official).

Using the driver results in this error:

```sql
SELECT * FROM dfs.my_parquets."Test" limit 10;
--
PARSE ERROR: Lexical error at line 1, column 19. Encountered: "`" (96), after : ""  
SQL Query: ALTER SESSION SET `exec.query.max_rows`=501
```

From the error is obvious that Rider tries to execute this hidden query with backticked identifiers:

```
ALTER SESSION SET `exec.query.max_rows`=501
```

The problem is that the `quoting_identifiers` in target drill are not set to *`* (backtick) but to *"* (double quote).

As a connection string I'm using this: `jdbc:drill:drillbit=my-drill-instance;quoting_identifiers='"'`

Is there a way to tell the driver to use double quotes in the hidden queries?

Comment: At the moment there is no way to change quotes directly. I filed an [issue DBE-10801](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-10801) based on your description.

Answer (score 0):

[Manual shows](https://drill.apache.org/docs/lexical-structure/), that option should be passed without quotes:

`jdbc:drill:zk=local;quoting_identifiers=[`

`jdbc:drill:drillbit=my-drill-instance;quoting_identifiers="`

Comment: I tried that. This example throws error: `Connect string 'drillbit=my-drillbit;quoting_identifiers="' contains unterminated quoted value ''`

Comment: My bad, correct one is `jdbc:drill:drillbit=localhost;quoting_identifiers='"'`. But there is an issue in Drill JDBC driver to set correct `LIMIT` value. 

As a workaround turn off **Limit page size to** option in _Preferences_ → _Database_ → _Data Views_ and set it manually for your queries. E.g.: `SELECT * FROM cp."employee.json" LIMIT 100`.

Comment: Also, you can skip _quoting_identifiers_ option and set it per session `ALTER SESSION SET planner.parser.quoting_identifiers = '"'`.